# spring mvc portlet with websphere portal

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, websphere-portal

I am working on a project with Spring MVC portlet, JSP, Javascript with AngularJS and Websphere Portal Server for deployment.

I use Liferay portal server just in unit test and integration testing with WebSphere IBM.

In this code I have some problemes when I insert it in Websphere but in liferayportal i don't have any problems.

In my page JSP I have this code :

```
  <table class="table" bordercolor="black" border="2" width="800">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
         <tr ng-repeat="elt in tabDemandes | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            <td> {{elt.id}} </td>
            <td  width="100"> {{elt.type}} </td>
            <td  width="150"> {{elt.date}} </td>
            <td>
               <input type="button" value="Detail" ng-click="maj_showDetail(elt.id,'showDetailByResp')" title="Voir plus de détail"/>
            </td></tr>
```

And in my function I have this code :

```
$scope.maj_showDetail= function(id,etat){
      var maj_showDetail= '${maj_showDetail}';
      document.location.href = maj_showDetail+ "&idDemande="+id+ "&etat="+etat;
};

<portlet:renderURL var="maj_showDetail">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="maj_showDetail"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
```

The problem is in id when I used liferay it worked but when I use Websphere it give me exception `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I dont have any problem with this id when I used liferay but with Websphere that give me `NullPointerException` or `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Where do you put that `<portlet:renderURL>` tag? Inside the AngularJS JavaScript files? Also, are you including the right portlet taglibs? On a sidenote, I suppose you're using Liferay for local development because it's more lightweight and easier to deploy on? You can also use WebSphere Liberty Profile with the Portal container addon on it, works as a charm as well.

Comment: yes I know this, and i put my <portlet : renderURL> inside code angularjs but the problem that when i send for example my Id in this example at a controler that not send a value of Id but elt.id

Comment: @g00glen00b you can give me your email to send you screenshot of my error and I want realy some one help me with easy documentation about websphere 8 for my project because i don't have enough time

Comment: I've never actually placed a portlet URL in a JavaScript/AngularjS file, I usually put it on the JSP in a `<script>` block. Anyways, the only moment I got a NPE in these cases is when I tried to use `<portal:defineObjects>` somehow, so try to remove that from your code if you have it. Also verify if your taglib is similar to mine `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>`

Comment: Anyways, here is an example portlet I once made with Spring portlet MVC and AngularJS, not sure if it's outdated or not though: https://github.com/g00glen00b/spring-marvel-portlet and here's a guide I wrote to locally develop on liberty profile using Eclipse: http://ibizz.be/digital-experience/developing-portlets-websphere-liberty-profile/. Both resources are not really maintained anymore and could be outdated, but it's better than nothing I guess.

Comment: ok thanks @ g00glen00b